Source for the story of the Shach's daughter and the nobleman
There is a legend, which has even been made into a kids' comic (can't find it I'm afraid - I believe it was written by Batsheva Ingber-Havlin) of the daughter of Rabbi Shabsi Cohen (AKA the Shach), who was lost to him while fleeing from the cossacks and was adopted by the king of Poland. see here for a rendition of the story.
Does anyone have a source for this (other than clearly fictional ones)? Is this story perhaps described by the Shach himself, or appear in any later sefer as fact or legend?

I don't know the origin, but I'm guessing Marcus Lehman popularized it with The Adopted Princess.
